# tables not being created in database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

Ok, I'm following a youtube guide on how to create a very simple blogging system using PHP/MySQL as I'd like to get to learn these 2 languages a bit more. I'm creating this in my localhost, permissions set-up correctly.

The problem is, when I go onto localhost/tables.php, it comes up as white screen which it's supposed to, but it's not creating the relevant tables within the database?

Here's the code I'm using:

mysql.php

```
<?php
mysql_connect('localhost','username','password'); //where localhost is the host, username is the relevant username and password is the relevant password.
mysql_select_db('database'); //where database is the chosen database in which to drop the tables.
?>
```

tables.php

```
<?php
include "mysql.php";
$table = "ENTRIES";
mysql_query ("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `$table` (`ID` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT , PRIMARY KEY ( `id` ) )");
mysql_query ("ALTER TABLE `$table` ADD `TITLE` TEXT NOT NULL");
mysql_query ("ALTER TABLE `$table` ADD `SUMMARY` TEXT NOT NULL");
mysql_query ("ALTER TABLE `$table` ADD `CONTENT` TEXT NOT NULL");
?>
```

Nothing is appearing in the error log which is frustrating and not helping me diagnose the problem.

Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: try echoing `mysql error` using `mysql_connect() or die(mysql_error())` and `mysql_select_db() or die(mysql_error())`

Comment: I'd like to point out that `mysql` extension is deprecated. You should use `mysqli` od `PDO` instead.

Comment: @MohammadFaisal I tried this but nothing got threw up in the error log nor in the browser, just a white screen.

Comment: Is your mysql.php in the same directory as tables.php?

Comment: yep, both of them are in /var/www

Comment: Try also to `mysql_query(...) or die(mysql_error());`. Maybe your DB user has no right to perform a `CREATE` query. Using `mysqli` instead of `mysql` is strongly advices, but it will not solve this particular issue.

Comment: I'm using root as my DB user so it technically should have all privileges?

Answer (score 0):

As you have no errors run this code to show if you have created created the table **ENTRIES**.

```
<?php 
include "mysql.php";
$result = mysql_query("SHOW COLUMNS FROM `ENTRIES`");
if (!$result) {
    echo 'Could not run query: ' . mysql_error();
    exit;
}
if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        print_r($row);
    }
}
?>
```

**NOTE** As you are starting with MySQL you would be advised to use [**PDO**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.pdo.php) in place of the deprecated mysql_.

Here is a good [**tutorial**](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/)

**EDIT**
Following comments the following code lists databases and tables on server(Note uses deprecated mysql_ function).

Ensure that the proper parameters replace "XXX".

```
<?php
$host= "localhost";
$username="XXX";
$password="XXX";
$database="XXX";
$link = mysql_connect($host,$username,$password); //where localhost is the host, username is the relevant username and password is the relevant password.
$db_list = mysql_list_dbs($link);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_object($db_list)) {
     echo $row->Database . "\n";
     echo "<BR>";
}
echo "<BR>";
$result = mysql_list_tables($database);
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
for ($i = 0; $i < $num_rows; $i++) {
    echo "Table: ", mysql_tablename($result, $i), "\n";
    echo "<BR>";
}
?>
```

Comment: It's saying that I haven't selected a database? Although in mysql.php it clearly has the select_db command? I haven't got any spelling errors either.. hmm!

Comment: OK it's now saying ENTRIES doesn't exist however I thought that the first query in tables.php tells it to create a table called "ENTRIES" if it didn't exist?

Comment: @AndrewMatthew I tried your `table.php`with my own connection parameters and it creates table "ENTRIES". I have added code to list databases in your server and tables in selected database

Comment: Check the the table was not created by an earlier attempt. Table names are case sensitive in most Unixes, which you seem to be using.

Answer (score 0):

> Nothing is appearing in the error log which is frustrating and not helping me diagnose the problem

So your first poblem is to find out why it's not logging any errors. BTW it would also be a good idea to inject some echo / print statements to find out *where* it's failing.

Forget about the MySQL stuff and try:

```
<?php
trigger_error("Testing", E_USER_WARNING);
?>
```

Even though (once you've got the error reporting sorted out) you should get an error logged it will likely only contain a limited amount of information. Any time you call a mysql function, be via mysql_, mysqli or PDO, you should poll the return value and handle any error - even if it's just to echo the value to the screen.

> It's saying that I haven't selected a database

Possibly the user account you are connecting as does not have permission to access the database.